# How to perform text search in Mongo 3.x with java

Tags: java, mongodb, full-text-search

I tried using the db.runCommand() function, only to discover that the text search command is not working in 3.x.

In the mongo shell this works well:

```
collection.find({"$text": {"$search":"some text"}})
```

The next idea was of course to then simply take this and convert this to Java.

```
collection.find(new Document("$text", new Document("$search", "some text")));
```

It does not work. It would be great to get a hint on how to approach search in Mongo 3.x with the Java driver.

**WRONG**: It does work. But there is still an issue with double quotes within literal text.

Comment: I appear to have been wrong. It does work in Java. However, literal text search containing double quotes still seems a challenge. For instance searching for the literal occurrence of  Nickname: "Duke". Normally literal searches need to be embedded in \", but what to do with the " within the text?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code block and can search in MongoDB.

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject()
query.put(column_name, new BasicDBObject("$regex", searchString).append("$options", "i"));
DBCursor cursor = dbCollection.find(query);
```

In the above code, replcae **column_name** with the column in which you want to search, and in place of **searchString** add the value which you are searching for. And run this code sample.

Hope this will work fine.